# Is FastView removed in eclipse oxygen?

Tags: eclipse

Is fast view removed in eclipse oxygen? It was very useful for me when I'm in a maximized code editor.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fast view are still available in Eclipse Oxygen, but **maybe [*Show in the Original Location*](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.4/eclipse-news-part1.php#minimized-stack-option) is enabled by mistake**:

[image]

In addition, there is also an option per fast view regarding the size: right-click on the view button and choose *Orientation > Default* to make the view resizable horizontally and vertically.